# Free body diagrams

Tags: free-body-diagram

Your car is accelerating to the right from a stop. Identify all forces acting on the object and draw the free-body diagram.

My thinking was that the normal force is directly upwards and weight force directly downward, drag force pointing to the left and friction pointing toward the left also. However this was incorrect

Comment: Draw the free body diagram, right here.......take a pic of a small neat drawing, include everything on it, put  it on your post and tell us what you have done so far, but we can't do the homework for you, unless someone is in a good mood.....There is no guarantee you will get a full answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My thinking was that the normal force is directly upwards and weight force directly downward, drag force pointing to the left and friction pointing toward the left also. However this was incorrect

Most of that is correct, but the friction forces exerted on the car are exerted by the road on the tyres, which would mean they are going to the right, not the left, from the car's point of view. That's why the car is accelerating rightwards.